# How to use Intersection, union and subtraction in Vim regular expression character class

Tags: vim

In Vim regex character class such as [a-z], [0-9],

how can we use **intersection**, **subtraction** and **union** inside the character class?

e.g. in Java

`[a-c&&[b-z]]` implies [b-c]           (**Intersection**)

`[a-c&&[^bc]]` implies [a]             (**Subtraction**)

`[a-c[k-z]]`  implies [a-c] or [k-z]  (**Union**)

Comment: You can't.  If you expect Vim regexps to have the a syntax (or functionality) similar to Java regexps, you're mistaken.  Read the manual to find out what Vim can do: `:h regexp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim does not support Java's regular expression extensions for character classes.

But there are intersection, subtraction and union of regular expression atoms:

`[a-c]\&[b-z]` implies [b-c] (Intersection)

`[a-c]\&[^bc]` implies [a] (Subtraction) (more general negation via `\@!`)

`[a-c]\|[k-z]` implies [a-c] or [k-z] (Union)